# How to stop an setInterval in a function from another function without the use of global variables

Tags: javascript

I have my code setup like this to delete elements but I also want to stop some intervals that are associated with them, but I have no idea how to go about this. I know setInterval returns a reference id you can use to clear it but making use of that would make my code messy

```
(function()){
  $("#form").submit((e) => {
    for (let i; i < AddedServers; i++) {
      $("#" + i).remove(); //The intervals for updating the graphs are still running, TODO fix this.
    }
  });
})();

function createGraph() {
  setInterval(() => {

    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: *without the use of global variables* => Why not ?

Comment: your code is unclear. where do you call `createGraph`? Where do you create those intervals? How are the intervals associated with the elements you are removing?

Comment: Im not certain what your trying to do, but remember your dealing with an ASYNCHRONOUS method, therefore, we need to know all the details of the problem your trying to solve, so we can mentally map a call-stack and try to pinpoint the best way for you to use and stop using your setInterval() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be adding the timer id in each instance of your updating objects as an attribute; when the object is removed from your DOM you can also call `clearInterval` for that timer. If you cannot change what are the attributes (e.g. the objects are from a library) then you can use a parallel data structure like a `Set` to track what are the ones needing to be updated.

Possibly even better is having just one `setInterval` call in your code; so in case of need you can also suspend the update for all of them at once (e.g. when there is a modal dialog and you would prefer that objects are not updated in that case)...

```
let auto_updaters = new Set;
let auto_update = true; // set to false to temporarily suspend updates
setInterval(()=>{
    if (auto_udpate) {
        for (let x of auto_updaters) {
            x.update();
        });
    }
}, 1000);

function newView() {
    ...
    auto_updaters.add(g);
    return g;
}

function removeView(v) {
    ...
    auto_updaters.delete(v);
}
```

In case you also do not control when those objects are added or removed then the only solution I can think to is to actually have the interval function to scan the DOM for them and call the update.

If the update is frequent it may make sense to do a "full scan" to find the objects only once in a while (e.g. once per second) to avoid spending all your time on scanning or use a `MutationObserver` to find out when objects are added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this to clear the interval. Hope this would help to solve the problem

```
function deleteSomething(){
    var element=document.getElementById("elementId");
    var size=0;
    var id=setInterval(intervalFunction,400);
    function intervalFunction(){
       if(size==10){
           clearInterval(id);
         }else{
             size++;
             element.style.width=`${size}%`  
           }
     } 
    }
```

Comment: your issue in this code is not clear. Please describe what is the error that you are getting.